# Using a V-data-table component in Vuetify, how do i add a CRUD (refresh) action to the row where "Items per page" is?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuetify.js

beginner coder here (primarily a ux designer) and I have a v-data-table component which I want to add a refresh button to the bottom of the data table such as here:

[Data table from Vuetify documentation with refresh button added where I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfIqK.png)

My table uses solely templates and slots to add data to the table. My question is, if I want to add a refresh button to the bottom left of the table outside of the data (shown in the image), how can I accomplish this?  The code for the table in the image WITHOUT the refresh button is here (taken from Vue's data table page)

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-value="name"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

I tried adding the code for the refresh button inside the v-data-table but it doesn't do anything because I believe it requires a template. If I add it outside the table, it goes under the entire table, not just under the data where I want it. I'm not sure if Vue offers a template for v-data-table that lets you alter the bottom row with "items-per-page" text, but that is what I'm trying to accomplish. Vue documentation did not provide much help. Closest thing I could find was how to add CRUD actions to each individual row, or the header. I could not figure out how to add the CRUD action to the bottom left of the data table

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `v-slot:footer` and applying `position:absolute` to my icon so it stays on the bottom left. the code is:

```
 <template>
      <v-data-table
        v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        item-value="name"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-slot:footer>
          <v-icon style="position: absolute"> mdi-refresh </v-icon>
        </template>
     </v-data-table>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use slot for custom footer

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :items-per-page="5"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-value="name"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:footer.prepend>
      <div style="position:absolute; left:20px;">
        <v-icon> mdi-refresh </v-icon>
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
 </template>
```

and footer should be relative

```
.v-data-footer {
  position: relative;
}
```